# If $x_n=o(\alpha_n)$ and $y_n=o(\alpha_n)$, then $x_n+y_n=o(\alpha_n)$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, asymptotics

If $x_n=o(\alpha_n)$ and $y_n=o(\alpha_n)$, then $x_n+y_n=o(\alpha_n)$.

All I know is the definition of little oh notation being used, that is, $x_n=o(\alpha_n)$ means that there exists a sequences $\epsilon_n\geq 0$ with $\epsilon_n \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ and $|x_n|\leq \epsilon_n |\alpha_n|$. I'm not sure how to prove this result. Any solutions or hints are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that if $|x_n| \leq \delta_n \alpha_n$ and $|y_n| \leq \epsilon_n |\alpha_n|$, then
$$
|x_n + y_n| \leq |x_n| + |y_n| \leq (\delta_n + \epsilon_n)|\alpha_n|
$$

Comment: Can we take $\gamma_n=\delta_n + \epsilon_n$ and then we have that $x_n+y_n=o(\alpha_n)$?

Comment: @DerpMagoo that's exactly right.  We note that $\gamma_n \to 0$.

Comment: awesome, thank you : )

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
\bigg| \frac{x_{n}+y_{n}}{\alpha_{n}} \bigg| \leq \bigg| \frac{x_{n}}{\alpha_{n}} \bigg| + \bigg| \frac{y_{n}}{\alpha_{n}} \bigg|
$$
and that the right side $\to 0$ by assumption.

Comment: While this is useful for intuition, it requires particular care if $\alpha_n = 0$ for some $n$.

Comment: That depends on the original requirement as to whether $\alpha_{n} \neq 0$ for all $n$. @Omnomnomnom